# Transcription of Genes: Are Specific Transcription Factors + Enhancers Necessary?

Tags: gene-expression, transcription, gene-regulation

I learned about transcription in my AP Biology class and we discussed how transcription occurs, but I was wondering whether transcription always requires the enhancers, activators (specific transcription factors), DNA-bending proteins, etc. to be present, or if this is only used for higher-level production of RNA transcripts?

Can transcription occur if only the RNA Polymerase (I, II, or III) and the General Transcription Factors are present?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enhancers, activators, silencers, repressors are necessary in controlling of the transcriptional process. Utilization of enhancers/silencers plays a part in differentiation of developmental processes (i.e. maturation, growth)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhancer_(genetics)